# LogOut user from Azure mobile Service from hybrid mobile app

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services, kendo-mobile, google-account

I am following authentications steps for AMS as described here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/#caching

From Kendo UI mobile app (Javascript)
I can log in using Google as an authentication provider using `client.login("google")`, execute authenticated AMS custom API calls
and also doing `client.Logout()` via button, that seems to successfully disconnect me from AMS

On subsequent `client.login()`, however, I do not get the Google account login window. It is seemingly stored in a cookie and the user is logged in automatically, thus not giving me a chance to log in as another user.

I was wondering what additional actions besides `client.Logout()` I must do to initiate the Google login screen on the next session after the user decided to logout. I do not want to force the user out of his Google account, as this would be impolite, just log him out of my application.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but since it is not answered and I found it out recently I decided to post the answer here.

When you go to google.com you can add another account (top right icon). After that you can choose after each logout which account you want to use for your application to login. And you can even add other accounts to log in.